# How to do an in query in Firestore in datastore mode with keys

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

My Datastore is setup to be Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode and in the cloud console I can run the following query with no issues:

```
SELECT * FROM <kind> WHERE Key(<Kind>, <ID>) in references
```

Where references is a list type.
When I try to do this same query in code I get an error:

```
g = db.GqlQuery("select * from <kind> where Key(<kind>, <ID>) in references")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

BadQueryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-40-9151990a927b> in <module>()

----> 1 g = db.GqlQuery("select * from <kind>where Key(<kind>, <ID>) in references")


/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, query_string, *args, **kwds)

   2701       app, namespace = app

   2702 

-> 2703     self._proto_query = gql.GQL(query_string, _app=app, namespace=namespace)

   2704     if self._proto_query._kind is not None:

   2705       model_class = class_for_kind(self._proto_query._kind)


/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, query_string, _app, _auth_domain, namespace)

    288         break

    289     else:

--> 290       raise initial_error

    291 

    292   def __InitializeParseState(self):


BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Condition at symbol (
```

I also tried it like this and got the same error:

```
g = db.GqlQuery("select * from <kind> where :1 in references", <key>)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

BadQueryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-41-c98945c4f808> in <module>()

----> 1 g = db.GqlQuery("select * from <kind>where :1 in references", <key>)


/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, query_string, *args, **kwds)

   2701       app, namespace = app

   2702 

-> 2703     self._proto_query = gql.GQL(query_string, _app=app, namespace=namespace)

   2704     if self._proto_query._kind is not None:

   2705       model_class = class_for_kind(self._proto_query._kind)


/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, query_string, _app, _auth_domain, namespace)

    288         break

    289     else:

--> 290       raise initial_error

    291 

    292   def __InitializeParseState(self):


BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol :1
```

What am I missing here. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values "Datastore mode indexes each unique array property value once per index. Thus to query if an array contains a value use an equality filter.".  So `select * from <kind> where references = Key(...)`